# Quasar dev, no me deja compilar ya que me sale un error

Tags: vue.js, cli, quasar

Buen dia,
Lo que pasa es que al momento de ejecutar "Quasar dev" me sale un error en cual indica que no el comando dev no es reconocido,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Evita lo más posible subir texto en imágenes, ya que no todos pueden visualizarla. Por otra parte, problemente el texto debajo de _important!_ te está dando una pista: ¿estás corriendo el comando **dentro de un proyecto Quasar** o fuera de uno? Especifica también en el título _cuál error_, ya que la pregunta/respuesta es útil no solo para ti, sino también para los demás que tengan un problema similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya me funciono, volver a instalar las herramientas y quitarle la restricción de los comandos asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: _Cuando haces preguntas o cuando las contestas, por favor no uses capturas de pantalla del texto_. [He aquí el porqué](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Además, lee [answer], y no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.